Pinecone Namespace Deletion and updation issue
In Pinecone, When I update vectors for two of my namespaces and subsequently call
index.describe_index_stats(),

it only returns the indexes that I haven’t updated recently. I understand this might be resolved with async-await. However, when I attempt to delete those unmodified indexes, I receive an error stating “maximum recursion depth exceeded.”
Can you help me troubleshoot this issue?
This is the code for deletion of namespaces:
before this code i was trying to modify some of the namespaces:
index.describe_index_stats()

it does not give me the namespaces i have just updated before executing it but gives me those unmodified namespaces.
okay i understand it might have happened because of not using async-await but then when i try to delete those unmodified namespaces it just gives a very big error stating that Recursive call exceeded !! I don't understand why recursive thing is coming here?
def delete_namespace_vectors(index_name):
    try:
        pinecone_api_key=os.getenv('PINECONE_API_KEY')
        pc = Pinecone(api_key=pinecone_api_key)

        list_indexes=[]
        index_description=pc.list_indexes()
        for desc in index_description:
            list_indexes.append(desc['name'])

        index = pc.Index(index_name)

        data=index.describe_index_stats()
        to_be_deleted_namespaces=list(data["namespaces"].keys())    
        
        for ns in to_be_deleted_namespaces:
            index.delete(delete_all=True, namespace=ns)
        
        return index.describe_index_stats()
    except Exception as e:
        return e

